# DB first Entity Framework query incredibly slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to databases, and to EF. I am using EF within an ASP.NET Core MVC project. The implementation code below is from a Controller, aiming to combine data from two tables into a summary.

The database has tables: Batch, Doc.

Batch has many columns, including: int BatchId, string BatchEnd. BatchEnd is a consistently formatted DateTime, e.g. 23/09/2016 14:33:21

Doc has many columns including: string BatchId, string HardCopyDestination. Many Docs can refer to the same BatchId, but all Docs that do so have the same value for HardCopyDestination.

I want to populate the following ViewModel

```
public class Batch
{
    public int BatchId { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }  // from BatchEnd
    public string HardCopyDestination { get; set; }
}
```

But my current query, below, is running dog slow.  Have I implemented this correctly?

```
var BatchViewModels = new List<Batch>();

// this is fine
var batches = _context.BatchTable.Where(
                  b => b.BatchEnd.Contains( 
                        DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")));  


// this bit disappears down a hole
foreach (var batch in batches)
{
    var doc = _context.DocTable.FirstOrDefault(
                  d => d.BatchId == batch.BatchId.ToString());

    if (doc != null)
    {
        var newBatchVM = new Batch
        {
            BatchId = batch.BatchId,
            Time = batch.BatchEnd.Substring(whatever to get time),
            HardCopyDestination = doc.HardCopyDestination 
        };

        BatchViewModels.Add(newBatchVM);
        continue;
    }
}

return View(BatchViewModels);
```

Comment: Why are you using strings to represent DateTime instances? You should use `System.DateTime` in .net (c#) and `DateTime2(7)` or `DateTime` in Sql Server (*You never mentioned your database server, if its not sql then use whatever that server type uses to represent date times but it will not be string)*. Also how a date is formatted (dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy or whatever) is a presentation layer solution and should never be carried down to the persistence layer.

Comment: You are doing some weird stuff with your dates

Comment: @Igor the database is designed and populated outside my sphere of influence.  I can influence my own ViewModel though, so yes, less fiddly to just parse it fully, then display as just the time element.

Comment: Types exist for a very good reason, otherwise everything would be string and we would just have "`the type`". I did not bring it up because its a little nuance, this *could* be the reason for your slowness. String comparisons can be very expensive. There are lots of other places in your code that it could also cause a problem but the biggest problem I see is not using the type system the way it was meant to be used (**dates are not strings and should never be persisted as such**).

Comment: BTW, you will not get any other good answers on your question because its not possible. You will have to do some searching on how to profile the database (whatever implementation you are using) and see what the calls are that are taking a long time and then go from there. It might be bad indexes, an enormous amount of data, the fact that you are re-executing another query inside the loop, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're hitting the database once per batch. If you have many batches that is expensive. You can get all documents in one go from db.

```
var batchDict = batches.ToDictionary(b => b.BatchId);
var documents = _context.DocTable.Where(doc => batchDict.Keys.Contains(doc.BatchId));
BatchViewModels.AddRange(documents.Select(d => new Batch
{
    BatchId = d.BatchId,
    Time = batchDict[d.BatchId].BatchEnd.TimeOfDay, // you only want the time?
    HardCopyDestination = d.HardCopyDestination
});
```

By the way, Igor is right about dates and in addition, if BatchId is int in BatchTable, then it should be that in DocTable as well. In above code I assume they are same type but shouldn't be so hard to change if they aren't.

Igor is also right about profiling db is a good way to see what the problem is. I'm just taking a guess based on your code.